# C++ vector of POINTs

Tags: c++, vector

In my program I am trying to get a set the current mouse position to a point, then fill an array with those points. Here is a small example where I only set the 0th index of the vector.

I get this error once it hits `pointList[0].x = p.x` line;

> An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

```
vector<POINT> pointList;
POINT p;
int i = 0;

while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {

    system("PAUSE");
    GetCursorPos(&p);  // When key is pressed unpauses and gets position

    pointList[i].x = p.x;
    pointList[i].y = p.y;

    i++;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I have a feeling it is an issue with the vector being declared but not initialized?

Comment: You are correct. It is an issue with the vector being declared but not initialized. Specifically, `[]` assigns to an **existing** element in the vector, and the code attempts to assign values to nonexistent elements in the vector. Nothing in the shown code actually adds anything to the vector, and undefined behavior results from the attempt to assign to nonexistent vector elements.

Comment: use `push_back()` every time you get new mouse position. Once you want to retrieve points, set some sort of for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the vectors using [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) you need to declare and initialise along with size of the vector.

for example -

```
std::vector<int> myvector (10);   // 10 zero-initialized elements
myvector[0] = 0;                  //this is valid
```

Else if you want dynamic allocation use [push_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) like -

```
vector<POINT> pointList;
POINT p;
int i = 0; //not required

while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {

  system("PAUSE");
  GetCursorPos(&p);  // When key is pressed unpauses and gets position

  pointList.push_back(p);  //entire <POINT> 'p' is inserted into end of the vector.

  i++; //not required
}
```

Comment: There's also [std::vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), depending on your needs.. or `insert`.

Comment: *If you want to access them as arrays you need to ...* this is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Is it correct now? @CroCo